# Screen Recording Using Selenium In C#

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, video-recording, remotewebdriver

I have the following question. I want to record the video of selenium RemoteWebDriver test steps in .Net Framework and the only good way to do it (that i found) was Microsoft.Expressions.Encoder which is already depracated. I tried to add an AdditionalCapability to my ChromeDriver but I think it doesnt work as I expect. If someone had done it, please share it. Much appreciated

```
  var chromeOps = new ChromeOptions();
  chromeOps.AddAdditionalCapability("video","True",true);
   _driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(seleniumHost), chromeOps);
```

If something additional has to be done or shared with you, let me know!